# Can't determine width of table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Oddly enough, I cannot seem to figure out why I can't return the width of the table view cell in this code. This is located in my custom UITableViewCell. My goal is to create a gradient that extends the width of the cell so certain text can be readable and not be obscured by a picture lying underneath. The gradient appears but seems to extend about 9/10 to the edge of the screen. I thought it may have something to do with an accessory view although i set it to none. After several adjustments, I can't figure out why it's not extending the width of the cell. I don't want to hard code a value to be lazy, just looking to understand why this is occurring in hopes to avoid it in the future. Thanks!

```
//Adds Gradient to the information background to allow text to be readable
func addGradientForInformationBackground(){
    InformationBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer();

    gradientFrame = self.frame;

    //build the colors array for the gradient
    var colors = NSArray(array:[UIColor.clearColor().CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3).CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6).CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7).CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9).CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]);

    //apply the colors and the gradient to the view
    gradient.colors = colors as [AnyObject];

    self.InformationBackground.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0);
}
```

Comment: try to get cell content view width not cell width

Comment: have already tried that, doesn't work :/ same effect

Comment: If it's a grouped table view try getting the `backgroundView.frame`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not , just a standard table view with custom cells . I have a 6 plus and it reads the width as 320

Comment: set the frame of gradient inside the CustomCell's layoutSubviews method

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on where you call your method `addGradientForInformationBackground()`.

Here is one scenario I think might lead to your situation：

1. you create a custom cell in xib (maybe 320 width)
2. during the init process you called `addGradientForInformationBackground()` at that time the cell's width is indeed 320 as the xib
3. cell loaded into tableView but tableView won't accept cell with different width with itself so tableView somehow call cell.setFrame to change width of cell
4. but the frame of layer you added won't change

so try to call the add layer method in `prepareForReuse` check if the layer existed if not create it

Comment: I think you're right , my xib is 320 so I'm thinking I should modify the gradient after the subviews are layed out accordingly . I will try it soon and let you know . Thanks for helping me understand